# Pearson´s correlation coefficient

Tags: mathematical-statistics

[image]What´s the easiest way to prove this relationship for Pearson´s c.c.

$$\frac{E((X-\mu)(Y-\nu))}{\sqrt{E((X-\mu)^{2})E((Y-\nu)^{2})}}=\frac{E((X_{1}-X_{2})(Y_{1}-Y_{2}))}{\sqrt{E((X_{1}-X_{2})^{2})E((Y_{1}-Y_{2})^{2})}},$$

where $(X_{1},Y_{1}),(X_{2},Y_{2})$ are i.i.d. as $(X,Y)$ and $E(X)=\mu, E(Y)=\nu.$

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: The question seems strange to me, the [Pearson's correlation][1] is a bivariate correlation. It is a measure of the linear correlation between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ or $X_1$, $X_2$. But for your right hand side equation, there are four random variables $X_1$,$X_2$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$, how can you calculate the pearson's $\rho$?


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient

Comment: I have found this relationship in my statistical books without proof (and can´t proove it by myself), so i was wondering what´s the way to proove that.

Comment: Anyway, I wonder if there are some confusitons between $\rho$ and $r$ which is the pearson's correatlion for a sample. Maybe you can take a picture of your statistical book and we can have a look?

Comment: Ok, i will post it here...It´s from the book (Jammalamadaka, Sengupta, Circular statistics).

Comment: I hope too. At least, thank you for your try to help me.

Comment: It might help to provide some more context about the argument leading up to this point.

Comment: There is nothing more, than normal definition of Pearson´s c.c. some of his properties and then this section.